# JQuery: How to get divs by class name from HTML data without root element

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, classname

I have such html data:

```
<div class="class1">...</div>
<div class="class1 class2">...</div>
<div class="class3">...</div>
...
<div class="class1">...</div>
<div class="class1 class2">...</div>
<div class="class3">...</div>
```

How can I get divs with class1 and then divs with class2?

I tried such way:

```
var divs = $(data).find('.class1');
```

But it returned empty array.

I tried other way:

```
var divs = $(data).filter('.class1');
```

But it returned array

```
[div.class1, div.class1, ..., div.class1].
```

So, I could not find divs with 'class2' in it, because 'class2' was lost... It's so strange...

Has anybody ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: where does `data` comes from?

Comment: What do you want to do once you will get the data. Loop trought it?

Comment: Seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/NBPSS/.  Or maybe I'm not understanding your problem.  Can you please clarify?  Or post a jsFiddle that illustrates your problem?

Comment: Yeah, David. I want to get array of divs with class name 'class1'. And then I need loop throught it to choose divs with class name 'class2' and process some functions. So, I shouldn't get divs with class name 'class2' directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why `find` didn't work is probably because your HTML string doesn't have a root element, so the search is performed inside of each element.  If you wrapped the HTML inside of a containing element, `find` should work.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I can use `$j('<div></div>').append(data).find('.class1');` But it's more interesting to get to know alternative way.

Comment: I guess, this way is the most convenient. Well, I vote for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `filter` on a collection, you get only the elements that match that filter. However, the original collection is not being modified.

All you have to do is store the original collection in a variable, and refer back to that when you want to filter by `.class2`:

```
var all = $(data),
    class1 = all.filter('.class1'),
    class2 = all.filter('.class2');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div[class*='class1']");
```

To test, run this code:

```
var divs = $("div[class*='class1']");

divs.each(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: It returns array with 'div.class1' only, but not with 'div.class1 class2'.

Comment: So, It is possible to use `var divs = $("div[class^='class1']");`, but it is not reliable style.

Comment: var divs = $("div[class*='class1']");

That code will work. the *= will search within the class attribute for class1. I edited the original post to include *=